# Double pointer AVL Tree in C

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, binary-tree, avl-tree

Im practicing my AVL tree using pointer. But i cant move on on balancing it if i cant even make an unbalanced tree. I think there is something wrong with how i use my pointers. Here is my code:

```
typedef struct structNode {
   int data;
   struct structNode *left;
   struct structNode *right;
   int height;
} sNode;

void createTree(sNode **node);
void insertNode(sNode **node, int num);

void main(){
   sNode * root = NULL;
   createTree(&root);
}

void createTree(sNode **root){
   int i, num, nodes;

   printf("\n\t\t\t\tNumber of nodes?\n");
   nodes = numScan(1,6);

   for(i=0;i<nodes;i++){
       num = numScan(1,100);
       insertNode(&*root,num);
   }


   printf("\n\n\t\t\t\tPress any key to continue.");
   getch();
}

void insertNode(sNode **root, int num){
   if(*root == NULL){
       sNode *node = malloc(sizeof(node));

       *root = node;

       node->data = num;
       node->left = NULL;
       node->right = NULL;
       node->height = 1;

       return;
   }

   sNode *node = *root;

   if(num < node->data){
       node->left = insertNode(&node->left, num); //void value not ignored as it ought to be
   }
   else
       node->right = insertNode(&node->right, num); //void value not ignored as it ought to be
   }
}
```

Im basing my code from this site but it doesnt use double pointer so im having troubles learning

site: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/avl-tree-set-1-insertion/

edit: numScan(a,b) basically just scans for a string and figure outs if its a number array or not so that all inputs are numbers (so there are no letters or characters inputted). the numbers in num scan (a and b) are just the range of number allowed to be inputted.

Comment: what `numScan()` does ? Also `&*root` is wrong while calling `insertNode(&*root,num);` --> `insertNode(&root,num);`

Comment: Oh yeah im sorry i forgot to add it, it basically just scans for a string and figure outs if its a number array or not so that all inputs are numbers. the numbers in num scan are just the ranges allowed to be inputted.

Comment: What you've implemented here isn't AVL. It's simply an unbalanced binary tree.

Comment: "Doesn't run" is not specific enough. Exactly what is happening? Also, you should provide a minimal, _complete_ example that shows the behaviour.

Comment: A good place to start is [C AVL Tree](http://www.zentut.com/c-tutorial/c-avl-tree/)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thanks for the site, ill make sure to study it through and through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As duskwuff said this is a simple unbalanced binary tree, not an AVL one. However, your code is not that bad:

```
void createTree(sNode **pRoot){
   int i, num, nodes;

   printf("\n\t\t\t\tNumber of nodes?\n");
   nodes = numScan(1,6);

   for(i=0;i<nodes;i++){
       num = numScan(1,100);
       insertNode(pRoot,num); //Just pass the pRoot as it is
   }


   printf("\n\n\t\t\t\tPress any key to continue.");
   getch();
}

int insertNode(sNode **root, int num)
{   //returns the new height of *root
   if(*root == NULL){
       sNode *node = malloc(sizeof(node));

       *root = node;

       node->data = num;
       node->left = NULL;
       node->right = NULL;
       node->height = 1;

       return 1;
   }

   sNode *node = *root;
   int SubtreeHeight;

   if(num < node->data){
       SubtreeHeight = insertNode(&node->left, num); //child enters itself at &node->left if needed
   }
   else
       SubtreeHeight = insertNode(&node->right, num); 
   }
   if (SubtreeHeight>=node->height) //if new subtree is higher.. 
      node->height = SubtreeHeight + 1; //plus node itself
   return node->height;
}
```

Comment: @JezT: Just noticed, my calculation of the height is wrong. And as duskwuff said this is a simple unbalanced binary tree, not an AVL one

Comment: Oh, no problem man, all i needed was to at least make a tree unbalanced or not. youve already helped me a lot. ill figure the rest out